# Countdown in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I'm trying to have, on a registered.php page, a countdown that shows a timer that starts from 3 secs and goes down second by second, redirecting to another page in the end.
However, when I load the page in my browser i'm redirected to the other page in an instant. Can someone help me figure out why?

```
    The registration was successful, you will be redirected in <span id="num"></span> seconds.
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            for (var i = 3; i>0; i--) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#num").html(i);
                },1000);
            }
            window.location.replace("login.html");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't block the script execution, and the `for` loop is executed within nanoseconds, after that a new location is set.

Comment: I'm new to javascript so I thought I could use like a sleep() method, but I guess that's not the proper way to do it then

Comment: Yes, it would be an inproper method, since there's no `sleep` method in JS. At first, you've to use `i * 1000` as a delay value, then create a counter that counts how many seconds has gone. Then when meeting `3`, redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a redirection page, you might not want to include the whole jQuery library for this bit of code:

```
var remaining = 3;

function countdown() {
    document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = remaining;
    if (!remaining--) {
        window.location.replace("login.html");
    }
    setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

window.onload = countdown;
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Very much agreed that including jQuery for this would be pointless, but I think this does still need to be bound to the document load event since you're grabbing a DOM element which isn't guaranteed to be available yet. (Also might be worth noting that IE < 10 does not support additional args to setTimeout.)

Comment: @Semicolon You're right, I updated my answer (with `window.onload` for widest support, and the use of a global variable instead of a parameter for the remaining time).

Answer (score 1):

Proper way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 3;
    $("#num").html(i);
    setInterval(function () {
        if(i==0){window.location.replace("login.html");}
        i--;
        $("#num").html(i > -1 ? i : 0);
    }, 1000);

});
```

setInterval would execute every second the function, but with the code you had, you just set `setTimeout` to execute after a second, but it didn't stop you from looping further. So you immediately had three timeouts set and then redirected.

Comment: Nit pick: this will wait a second before showing the initial value of 3 (and the overall countdown time will end up being 4 seconds, give or take).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer = 3;
    var clearTime = setInterval(function(){
        $("#num").html(timer--);
         if(timer == 0){
             window.clearInterval(clearTime);
             window.location.replace("login.html");
         }
    },1000);
});
```